# Latest and currently utilized research on modeling option pricing with IV smile

Tags: options, option-pricing, finance, quantitative

As per title, where would I find the latest research papers on modeling option pricing, accounting for IV smile?
I'm specifically interested in papers that already found practical application in some form by any trading firms, or may be considered by, or recommended to them.
I'd also be interested in any practical implementations, examples, code, etc.